# How do I configure the GMail notifier?

Tags: password, gmail

I changed my GMail password and since then my gm-notify doesn't work, even after reinstalling. I can't find anywhere to manage my gm-notify account.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The utility to manage *gm-notify* is called `gm-notify-config`.

To start it from the Dash, simple type `gm...` as shown below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also press `Alt+F2`, type `gm-notify-config` and press `Enter`.