# How do I configure program Gmail-notify?

Tags: configuration, gmail

I have installed  Gmail-notify but I can't configure it. I entered Username and Password, but it is not enough. There is one more free field Proxy. What should I fill in?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/162966/

Comment: @JerareYoshi Not really a dupe as this question asks for specific configuration settings that are not actually addressed in the possible dupe question...

Comment: Have you entered you username without the '@gmail.com' at the end? This is a requirement of the application...